# How to set Up A Payment Gateway in Android App using My Bank Account For Testing

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I am developing an android app which accepts payment through Netbanking as well as Credit Cards. I am residing in India currently. My requirement is;

1. The User owe me (me here is my company) $100. He types in the amount and click on pay button.
2. Now here the user should redirect to payment gateway where he enters credit card details or netbanking.
3. When he press pay the money should get to my company account (I will use my personal account for testing). The personal account I will be using is ICICI Bank.

My Doubts

1. What is the feasibility of such a service. Is there any free payment gateway's available for testing or limited transaction?
2. How does invoking the external payment gateway works? Is it like a POST request where I will send the customers details to this third party gateway?
3. What will be the system that Amazon, Flipkart, Mytra will be using for collecting the money from customer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to integrate bank specific payment gateway then you need to setup a merchant account with your bank, then they will provide you libraries and technical documents for guideline of integrating their payment gateway.

**Other option** is to go with third party payment gateways like **PayPal, CCAvenue or InstaMojo** to name a few.
each has their pros and cons.
I would recommend Instamojo, because of their easy integration steps.
For setting up a test account with them you can signup on

http://test.instamojo.com

Hope this answers your query.